# PlayHaven Content was dismissed iOS

Tags: ios, playhaven

> The request was successful but did not contain any displayable content. This may have occurred because there are no content units assigned to this placement; all content units assigned to this placement are suppressed by frequency caps or targeting; no ad campaigns are available at this time; or an invalid placement was requested. Visit the PlayHaven Dashboard for more details. Dismissing now.
> PlayHaven: Content was dismissed!

Answer (score 1):

This error lets you know that the placement you requested works. But is not currently hooked to a content unit. To fix this log into your Upsight account and click on marketing. Then click on your game and click "add content" from here select the content unit you want and associate it with the placement you requested.

For example if you wanted a more games widget on your "game_pause" placement you would call "game_pause" in the app itself. On the website you would create a new more games widget in the dashboard and then select "game_pause" in the placement selection menu.